# Difficulty understanding in substution method

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, recurrence-relations

I'm researching recursive functions. I see that there is a method to solve them known as substution method. It is used like $n = 2^m$ or $n= 2^k$

For example, [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/779994/solving-divide-and-conquer-recurrence),

$$T(n) = n^2 + \frac{n}{2} - 1 + T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)$$

I tried to substitute $n=2^m$, which yields the following recurrence:

$$S(m) := T(2^m)$$
$$S(0) = 1$$
$$S(m) = 4^m + 2^{m-1} - 1 + S(m-1)$$

How does it become $S(m-1)$? I would say $S(2^{k}*2^{-1})$. I don't understand it.

In the same way, in other question as well,

Use substitution

$$S(n) = T(2^n) =2T\left(\frac{2^n}2\right)+2^n = 2T(2^{n-1})+2^n = 2S(n-1)+2^n
$$

I don't understand how it becomes $S(n-1)$.

Could you please explain it?

Comment: You have defined that $$ n = 2^m $$ and $$ S(m) = T(2^m) = T(n) $$ which means $$ T \left(  \frac{n}{2} \right) = T\left(  \frac{2^m}{2} \right) = T\left(  2^{m - 1} \right) = S(m - 1) $$ by definition.

Comment: @prcssngnr how and why?

Comment: Because $ S(m) = T(2^m) $ and $\frac{n}{2} = \frac{2^m}{2} = 2^{m - 1}$.

Comment: @prcssngnr that why I expect actually. $S(m*2^{-1})$ How is $2^{-1}$ directly written as $m-1$?

Comment: You defined $S(m) = T(2^m) = T(n)$. This means $S(m - 1) = T(2^{m - 1}) = T \left( \frac{2^m}{2} \right) = T \left( \frac{n}{2} \right)$. What is happening here is that we have $T(2^m)$ and we abstract this away by defining a new function $S(m) = T(2^m)$.

Comment: It is analogous to the following. Consider a function $f(n) = n + 1$ and define $n = \sqrt{m}$ and $g(m) = f(\sqrt{m}) = f(n)$. Then, we have $g(m) = f(\sqrt{m}) = \sqrt{m} + 1$. So we defined a relation $n = \sqrt{m}$ and a function $g(m) = \sqrt{m} + 1$ equivalent to $f(n)$, i.e. $g(m) = f(n)$. This function may be stated as $g(m)$ or $f(\sqrt{m})$ which correspond to $S(m)$ or $T(2^m)$ in your problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
T\left(2^{\log_2 n}\right) = T\left(2^{\log_2 n-1}\right)+n\left(n+\frac 12\right)-1
$$

now calling $\log_2 n = z$ we have

$$
T\left(2^z\right) = T\left(2^{z-1}\right)+2^z\left(2^z+\frac 12\right)-1
$$

so the recurrence can be recast as

$$
S(z)=S(z-1)+2^z\left(2^z+\frac 12\right)-1
$$

with solution

$$
S(z) = \frac{1}{3} \left(3\cdot 2^z+2^{2 z+2}-3 z-7\right)+c_0
$$

and finally we return to $T(n)$ backwards with $z = \log_2 n$ obtaining

$$
T(n) = \frac 13\left(4n^2+3n-7\right)-\log_2 n+c_0
$$

NOTE

After substitution, $S(z) = S\left(\log_2 n\right) = T\left(2^{\log_2 n}\right) = T(n)$.

Equivalently, considering now

$$
T(n) = T\left(\frac na\right)+f(n),\ \ \ a > 0
$$

taking the subset $n = a^m$ and submitting the recurrence to this subset we have

$$
T\left(a^m\right) = T\left(a^{m-1}\right)+f\left(a^m\right)
$$

considering now $S(\cdot) = T\left(a^{(\cdot)}\right)$ for clearer writing, we follow with

$$
S(m) = S(m-1) + f(a^m)
$$

with solution

$$
S(m) = \sum_{k=0}^m f(a^k)
$$

and returning to the original formulation

$$
S(m)=T\left(a^m\right)=T(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{\log_a n} f(a^k)
$$

Note that the recurrence $S(m)$ operates in a subset of $T(n)$ but at those points they have the same value.

Comment: I dont understand how S(z-1) is substituted. I expect $S(z*2^{-1})$ ? Furthermore, why are not other $2^z$ s changed to $z$?

Comment: $S(\cdot) = T\left(2^{(\cdot)}\right)$ and then $S(z-1) = T\left(2^{(z-1)}\right)$

Comment: why are not other $2^z$  s changed to z?

Comment: Could you tell me at what step in the calculations?

Comment: $$
S(z)=S(z-1)+2^z\left(2^z+\frac 12\right)-1
$$

Comment: Note that making $z = \log_2 n$ we have $n(n+\frac 12)-1\Rightarrow 2^z(2^z+\frac 12)-1$

Comment: The problem is that we change as S(z-1) but 2^n expressions out of S(...) remain same. Why don't we write z for 2z(2z+1/2)?

Comment: Recasting the recurrence is the same as renaming it. Essentially all remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeking a canonical representation of the problem

$$
T(n)=T\bigg(\frac{n}{2} \bigg)+f(n)
$$

where $f(n)$ is a polynomial in $n^k$. So, let's first consider the simpler monomial case of $f(n)=cn^k$. Using the substitution method discussed above, it can be shown that

$$
S(m)=S(0)+c\sum_{j=1}^m(2^k)^j=S(0)+c\frac{2^k}{2^k-1}\big(2^{km}-1\big)
$$

and

$$
T(m)=T(1)+c\frac{2^k}{2^k-1}\big(2^{k\log_2 n}-1\big)
$$

where it is understood that

$$
\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{2^k}{2^k-1}\big(2^{k\log_2 n}-1\big)=\log_2 n
$$

It is now a short leap to show that for a polynomial,

$$
T(m)=T(1)+\sum_j c_j\frac{2^{k_j}}{2^{k_j}-1}\big(n^{k_j}-1\big)
$$

In your case, we have $k=[0;1;2]$ and $c=[-1;1/2;1]$. I have verified this numerically, as well.

Comment: My intention is not to solve the problem. I want to learn how the substution is made. Can you please look at my last comment in Cesareo's post?

Comment: What is 2^(m-1)? It’s totally simply except you don’t seem to get it. Or your brain refuses to see it.

Comment: @SonerfromTheOttomanEmpire You are overthinking this. It's simply this: if $n=2^m$ then $n/2=2^m/2=2^{m-1}$. That is how exponents work.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a simpler case:

$$T(n)=T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+n$$

$T$ is a function of $n$ that satisfies the above equation for *all* values of $n$. Here comes the tricky part. Since the equation is valid for all values of $n$, in particular it is for $n=2^m$. The expression evaluated (we just replace n for $2^m$) is
\begin{equation}\label{expression with m}
    T(2^m)=2^m+T\left(\frac{2^m}2\right)=2^m+T\left(2^{m-1}\right).
\end{equation}
You can now define a *different*, auxiliary function $S$. You may define it as $S(m)=T\left(2^m\right)$; that is, for every given value $m$, exponenciate 2 to $m$ and then evaluate $T$ at this new value. Now note that $S(m-1)=T(2^{m-1})$, because you take the value $m-1$, exponenciate $2$ to it, and then evaluate $T$ at this new value (this is how you defined $S$ in the first place). Reading some other comments I see that this part might be problematic to understand, so another way of seeing it is by simply defining a value $a=m-1$. Then, $S(m-1)=S(a)=2^a=2^{m-1}$-

Then, the equality above becomes
$$S(m)=2^m+S(m-1).$$

The same reasoning can be used with the function you provided. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. I'm still struggling with it. If you can help me, could you please look at this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4850519/reccurence-solution-no-using-master-theorem-that-tn-3tn-3n-log-n-t1-1

Answer (score 1):

We can consider the calculation as two-step approach. We start from
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{T(n) = n^2 + \frac{n}{2} - 1 + T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}
\end{align*}

**First step:** Substitution $n=2^m$

When we *substitute* $n=2^m$ we obtain by replacing each occurrence of $n$ with $2^m$:
\begin{align*}
T\left(2^m\right) &= \left(2^m\right)^2 + \frac{2^m}{2} - 1 + T\left(\frac{2^m}{2}\right)\\
&=4^m+2^{m-1}-1+T\left(2^{m-1}\right)\tag{1}
\end{align*}

**Second step:** Introducing function $S$

We introduce a new function $S$, given for natural numbers $m$ as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{S\left(m\right)=T\left(2^m\right)}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

In (2) we obtain by *substituting* $m$ with $m-1$:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{S\left(m-1\right)=T\left(2^{m-1}\right)}\tag{3}
\end{align*}

> From (2), (3) and (1) we conclude
> \begin{align*}
> T\left(2^m\right) &= 4^m+2^{m-1}-1+T\left(2^{m-1}\right)\tag{$\to\mathrm{(1)}$}\\
> \color{blue}{S(m)}&\color{blue}{=4^m+2^{m-1}-1+S(m-1)}\tag{$\to\mathrm{(2),(3)}$}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

Comment: @SonerfromtheOtomanEmpire: Many thanks for granting the bounty.

Comment: You're welcome. If possible, can you look at the question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4850519/reccurence-solution-no-using-master-theorem-that-tn-3tn-3n-log-n-t1-1